# Reconnect logic on connection close in X DevAPI of MySql using @mysql/xdevapi module in Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reconnect, mysql-x-devapi

I am using [X DevAPI](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/) of [MySql v8.0.33](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) using [@mysql/xdevapi v8.0.33](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mysql/xdevapi).

I have reconnect logic added but that is not working. Here is that code.

```js
const mysqlx = require('@mysql/xdevapi')

async function createSession() {
  try {
    const session = await mysqlx.getSession({
      user: 'your_user',
      password: 'your_password',
      host: 'your_host',
      port: 33060, // default MySQL X Protocol port
    });

    // Handle connection close by reconnecting the session
    session['_client']['_stream'].on('close', () => {
      console.log('Connection closed. Reconnecting...');
      createSession(); // Re-establish the session
    });

    // Use the session for your database operations
    // ...

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error connecting to MySQL:', error);
  }
}

// Create the initial session
createSession();
```

I am getting error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_stream')
```

This error means that `session['_client']` is `undefined`.

What is wrong with my reconnect logic?

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, `session['_client']` is not defined nor available. I guess you can get a socket reference with `session.getConnection_().getClient().getConnection()`, however this is an internal API and is prone to breaking changes without notice, so I would probably not recommend it. Instead, you can have some kind of decorator that wraps your workflows and creates a connection if one is not available.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js

Comment: Thanks for this answer. What should be right way to use reconnect logic which I can sue in my express.js application?